# How do I safely store database login and password in a C# application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, passwords

I have a C# application that needs to connect to an SQL database to send some data from time to time. How can I safely store the username and password used for this job?

Comment: save paswword by converting it md5 algorithm Value

Comment: If possible use integrated security, otherwise, as mentioned above, consider encrypting the password.

Comment: @satindersingh & how would you get the password back? md5 is a 1 way algorithm.

Comment: @SimonHalsey good point, SQL Server needs the actual user/password (SQL authentication mode)

Comment: @SimonHalsey: at revcieing point you can convert md5 value into string,

Comment: @satindersingh are you sure you understand the problem? We're not checking the password, SQL Server is, so we need the actual password to give to it. If you hash it using MD5, you can't get it back.

Comment: @SimonHalsey: yeah i was going to another direction, wll thanks for correction :)

Answer (score 4):

Use integrated Windows authentication whenever possible. It takes the onus off of your application and lets Windows handle it. Using Windows authentication instead of SQL authentication is considered a best practice.

Read this accepted answer: [the best way to connect sql server (Windows authentication vs SQL Server authentication) for asp.net app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432793/the-best-way-to-connect-sql-server-windows-authentication-vs-sql-server-authent)

See also: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1831/using-windows-groups-for-sql-server-logins-as-a-best-practice/

And: http://www.greensql.com/content/sql-server-security-best-practices

Incidentally, if this is a "job" as implied by the question, it may be a great candidate for a simple Windows service or scheduled task, both of which can run in a specific security context (i.e. as a specific Windows user).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the RijndaelManaged key, which is quite a secure symmetric encryption key. A good article on this information (and tutorial) can be found here;

http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx

Comment: link doesn't work anymore. Maybe this links from Microsoft might be useful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.generatekey?view=net-8.0

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about your exact requirements, but first and foremost, you have to encrypt the password.
Also, when transmitting such sensitive information, consider using a secured connection.

Comment: I don't think data is as sensitive. He means to keep the db username/password confidential.

Answer (score -1):

Store an encrypted version in your connection string and form the connection string programmatically after decrypting the password.

You could use any encryption mechanism of your choice - from trivial to complex.

Answer (score -1):

you can use encryption and dyscryption algorithm for passwords and log your user information by who created user and what datetime it created and save this in database.
 and even if someone update or edit log that information in database.

Comment: I think that's already been suggested, but with an actual implementation reference

Answer (score -6):

**Code** to Convert stirng into md5

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
    public static string ConvertStringtoMD5(string strword)
        {
            MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strword);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
               { 
                    sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("x2"));
               }
               return sb.ToString();
       }
```

Comment: And how would SQL Server use your MD5 hash?

Comment: Not only is MD5 broken but its a hash; one way and useless as far as this scenario is concerned.

Comment: *MD5's designer Ron Rivest wrote, "md5 and sha1 are both clearly broken (in terms of collision-resistance)."* - see "Security" section at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5