# Programming c# Entity Framework: Manage User Login

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm writing a WPF desktop application using Entity Framework to persist user data. I'm using a code first approach and a new database.

In certain scenarios, I would like to restrict access to the database solely from the application, i.e. no user should be able to log into the database outside of the application (e.g. using Management Studio).

I'm struggling to make this work, and initially thought to have the database implement SQL authorization (as opposed to Windows authorization), and have the application generate a unique password on database create. Only the application will therefore know this password, and so only the application will be able to log in and edit the database.

My question is as follows: is this at all possible, i.e. can I generate the login details to the database from my C# application using Entity Framework? Are there any better solutions to this problem?

Comment: If you don't share the password nobody can access the database in the first place or don't you trust yourself? Also the database is created once so your code will generate a password once too. (If it would be recreated every time you startup the application there's not much benefit of using a database.)

Comment: I'm effectively trying to prohibit any user from making changes to the database outside of my application. In my mind the application will still be able to access the database, as it (and only it) will know the password. This will only be done once on database creation. Does it make more sense to simply implement an audit process to inform the user when changes were made to the database outside of my application?

Comment: You can just put your connectionstring hardcoded in your application

Comment: Your description sounds as if you want to use the "application role" feature, i.e. the MS "SQL Server" `sp_setapprole' procedure. I'd suggest to try a web search for terms like "entity framework application role"

Comment: if it is a desktop application, and the app knows the database credentials, an user can easily find the database credentials decompiling the app. If you are worried about someone accessing your db, you should use an client-server app instead of a desktop. You can still use wpf, but you should use external APIs to manage the database. In that case,  you should give access of the API to nobody

Comment: Fabio is not entirely correct. You can secure the connection string in your app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685206/how-do-i-safely-store-database-login-and-password-in-a-c-sharp-application