# Entity Framework Insufficient SQL Server Privileges

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have used Entity Framework 6 on another web application and database without issues, but I have now written a new windows forms program with EF6 that will only work if I use integrated security with the Server sysadmin role.

If I create a database login and map it to the databases I need with read, write, and admin roles I get a cannot create Table error due to insufficient privileges. If I use

```
this.SetDatabaseInitializer<Model>(null);
```

it doesn't return any data.

Something to note is that another application runs on these databases and uses Entity Framework without issue. I am unsure of which version. I have tried using the same login used by the other application and it still doesn't work.

Here is my connection string that doesn't work:

```
<add name="Model" 
     connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=username; Password=password; Persist Security Info=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This works:

```
<add name="Model" 
     connectionString="data source=server;initial catalog=database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I obviously can't make everyone a sysadmin so any help I could get would be greatly appreciated. I am pulling my hair out on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I am my own worst enemy. My connection string was pointed to the wrong database which was creating empty tables when I had privileges and returning nothing when I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with Entity Framework but in managing secure database access from a Windows fat client application.

The connectionstring in which you specify userid and password expects a SQL Server Login to have been created and granted the appropriate permissions on the target database server and resident database.  This, of course, requires the SQL Server to be configured to allow SQL Server logons in addition to Windows logons.  This means of application security makes perfect sense for a web app hosted by IIS but may not be the best for a client app.

Take a look at this SO question and related answers for good options.

[How do I safely store database login and password in a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685206/how-do-i-safely-store-database-login-and-password-in-a-c-sharp-application)

I'd suggest going with your 2nd connectionstring that uses integrated security (meaning the currently authenticated Windows user account), creating a Windows group and granting the Windows group the necessary permissions on the target server and database.  That eliminates the need to secure your connectionstring with your deployed app to each of your clients and it allows you to easily manage permissions by maintaining the Windows security group.

Oh, do look into reducing access to something far below System Administrator access to your SQL Server.  Database Owner within your target database is probably sufficient even if you do need to create and modify schema...

Comment: I am planning on using integrated security but the problem is that anything below Server Admin doesn't work. I only used the sql login to test privileges.