# How to hide Database Password in Setting File

Tags: database, winforms, security, passwords, password-protection

I have a problem. I have saved more than one database's password in application setting file and read password in this file when application started.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Databases.Password
```

But, this is not secure. I want to make it secure. I use winforms.

Comment: That's a problem. Youn can get some ideas by reading the answers to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685206/how-do-i-safely-store-database-login-and-password-in-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: @Flocke no, this is not enought. because they are write manually connection string. but client is add database username and password in my application and i use sqldataAdapter for connect to database.

Comment: If you allow the client connect to database directly, then the user name and password belongs to them and protecting the username and password is not responsibility of your application. Instead, you need to restrict access of that specific username to be able to access just to authorized data. Also if you really care about securing your application, you need to put business logic on server side.