# How can I securely store a database connection string in a C# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, security, connection-string

I have a C# web app with a database connection string saved in the web.config file. This file is also part of a git repository. How can I save the connection string to prevent it from being compromised in case a bad actor gains access to my repository?

Would encrypting the file solve my problem like answers to [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685206/how-do-i-safely-store-database-login-and-password-in-a-c-sharp-application) suggest?
If yes, how can i do this in .NET?

Comment: Well the linked question gives you an kind of answer. Why do you need to push the web config with the credentials to git in the first place? Usually you would add them in your build process (with jenkins, azure dev ops or whatever) and only have it in the production system

Comment: `Using Windows Authentication is not really suitable for my projects as multiple web apps run on one web server and I would like to separate the access different applications have.` you don't have to use the same Windows account for all applications. In fact you have to do extra work to use the same account. Each application pool runs under its own virtual service account to begin with. If you want to use a domain account, use different AD accounts for each application

Comment: This is (at least) two separate questions in one. The first question paragraph is a nice self-contained question. I suggest you edit this question to be just that. In other words, how to store secrets securely in git.

Then you have question 2 which seems to be about protecting a web.config file (does that file need to be sent around in encrypted form?). And possibly a separate question 2b about how to provide credentials to a server process. I suggest to read up on those topics separately, and of course ask more SO questions if you don't find what you need :)

Comment: @HughW Thank you for your comment. I edited my question and hope it is clearer now. I only included the second part because i thought it might be a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your help. I'm using Jenkins but my Groovy script for the deployment is also part of my repository. If not from the repository where should Jekins get the connection string from? How would this improve security? (I'm sorry if this is a very nooby question but i'm relatively new in this field)

Comment: You can add credentials in Jenkins https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/ usually they consist of a username + password. These variables can then be injected for example in your web.config file during build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools for securely storing secrets in a Git repository, and you will find a great overview [here](https://medium.com/@slimm609/securely-storing-secrets-in-git-542771d3ed8c)<sup>([archive 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20221210012459/https://medium.com/@slimm609/securely-storing-secrets-in-git-542771d3ed8c), [archive 2](https://archive.is/UJWIo))</sup> that discusses the tradeoffs.

Of those mentioned in the article, I've only used [git-secret](https://git-secret.io/) which has this synopsis:

> 1. `git-secret` encrypts files and stores them inside your `git` repository, providing a history of changes for every commit.
> 2. `git-secret` doesn’t require any extra deploy operations other than providing the appropriate private key (to allow decryption), and using `git secret reveal` to decrypt all the secret files.

As for the broader question of how to provide passwords to an ASP.NET server, it's a big topic. I suggest reading the guide [Protecting Connection Strings and Other Configuration Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You should never commit sensitive data or credentials into fit.

You can use User Secrets to work locally.

When deploying to a server or hosting environment you should use environment variables.

This has the added benefit of allowing you to set different values in each environment.

Answer (score -2):

You should ( as i saw my projects ) store it in launchSettings.json.

Forexample

```
"environmentVariables": {
        "ConnectionStrings__MyDb":"Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=My;Trusted_Connection=True"
      },
```

This file is different for all programmers.

Comment: This doesn't address the part in the question where it asks _How can I save the connection string to prevent it from being compromised in case a bad actor gets access to my repository?_

Comment: Not "should you" do this. There's many different ways of solving this problem, and saying you should do something without mentioning the upsides, downsides, or alternatives is very misleading.